# Could the Higgs field be the result of an effective field theory according to an underlying gauge field?

Tags: gauge-theory, higgs, effective-field-theory

The quantum of the Higgs field, as far as I know, is considered as an elementary particle by the standard model. But it is peculiar in the sense that all the other fields of the standard model are either gauge fields or fermions minimally coupled to them, whereas the Higgs field is nonlinear in a way that looks "arbitrary". Why not add $\phi^6$-terms or $\phi^8$-terms to the (free) Higgs action?

$$\mathcal{L}(\phi) = (\partial_{\sigma} \phi)^\dagger (\partial^{\sigma} \phi) + \mu^2 \phi^\dagger \phi - \lambda (\phi^\dagger \phi)^2+\dots$$

Gauge fields are just nonlinear in a geometric sense, i.e. there is basically just one unique possibility for each of them to be nonlinear without breaking gauge symmetry (much like general relativity is almost unique). Anything added to them makes them fail as a gauge theory.

Contrary to gauge fields, the Higgs field much looks like a "material law" in macroscopic physics, i.e. instead of introducing masses and interaction strengths between them, it includes "fit parameters" to make the Higgs match with experiments. Of course, the coefficient of the $\phi^2$-term is commonly interpreted as based on an "imaginary mass", but after all, Young's modulus in continuum mechanics is also a stress dimension-wise, but no matter how hard you search, you generally won't find a stress in your macroscopic matter, that has the value of Young's modulus. It is a macroscopic fit parameter that explains nothing about how its value is based on atomic interactions.

So, the question for me is, isn't it very likely that the Higgs field is composed of constituent particles that explain the coefficients of the Higgs "material law" (if you forgive me that suggestive terminology in the context of this question)? And, since gauge fields have been so successful, wouldn't the Higgs field be most likely composed of a (yet undiscovered) gauge field and corresponding fermions?

If yes, and if the question has been already investigated, what would be the simplest theory of that kind?

If no, in what do the properties of effective gauge field theories contradict the properties of the Higgs field?

Comment: Have you read up on [Technicolor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technicolor_(physics))?

Comment: I have heard about hardly more than the name, but got the impression that it's somehow "a weirder form of quarks". So if this the reference, I will give it a read.

Comment: I have quickly read through the Technicolor article of Wikipedia. It seems pretty fine-branched, given that all of this is only dedicated to explaining a single Spin-0 particle with two parameters. What I am missing is a kind of "minimal theory" or toy model that shows the principal suitability of that model for the Higgs mechanism. But in a sense, since this is ongoing research, this is probably the best answer to my question that I can expect as of today.

Comment: Nevertheless, it seems to me that the the majority of physicists accepts the possbility that the Higgs field is not the end of the story, but rather an effective field theory, right?